# Qt visualization as a function in separate file

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm newbie in PyQtGraph and Qt. I need to write a function (preferably in separate file) for visualization my data. The short version of my snippet is below. The function and the main code in the same file here:

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

def visualizator(image):
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    win.setCentralWidget(w)

    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    w.setLayout(layout)

    imgView = pg.ImageView()
    layout.addWidget(imgView)
    imgView.setImage(image)

    win.show()
    app.exec_()
    return

my_image = np.ones((256,256),np.float)
visualizator(my_image)
```

When I run my code I get Qt crash. What am I doing wrong? What should I `return` from my function?

Comment: did you checkout the examples folder.  Its easy to find a simple example and modify that code

Comment: Where is the examples folder? Could you give me a link @user1938107?

Comment: site-packages->pyqtgraph->examples is the source code.  call it by this method (second section from bottom) http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/introduction.html#examples

Comment: @user1938107 I know this examples. But where is an example with visualization as a function?

Comment: many of them have examples with visualization.  import examples and run it, you will be able to see all of them and easily try each one.  There is both 2d and 3d visualization

Comment: I've run it many times. But where is exactly an example with visualization as a function?

Comment: im sorry but i dont konw what you are talking about.  Visualization as 2d numpy input, 3d input, mesh data, or your "visualization" function.    What are you trying to visualize

Comment: I need to visualize 2D image but as a FUNCTION in separate file

Comment: your example only shows one file, and you say your example crashes, so its hard to understand what separate file your talking about

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with your QApplications. You don't want to start another one in a function. Try removing the app-stuff.